# Solve : If $a$, $b$, $c$ and d are in H.P then find the value of $\frac{a + b}{ a - b} - \frac{c +d}{c -d}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My try : First , I assumed an H.P and then got the answer.
Second , tried it by solving but found my method too long in which I have to find the value of a,b,c and d . I want to know how to deal with this problem without assuming H.P.

Pic of question - [image]

Comment: I think some parentheses are missing.  Please supply them.  I doubt you are asking about $a+\frac ba-b-c+\frac dc-d$ but that is what the title says.  We also like the body to be self-contained, not to just put the question in the title.

Comment: Do you mean _harmonic progression_ with H.P?

Comment: Given your title, what do you mean by "I want to know how to deal with this problem without assuming H.P."?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  means if we assume the H P ( harmonic progression ) be 1/2 , 1/4 , 1/6 then this question can be solved easily but  I want to how to solve it only in the terms of a , b ,c  and d

Comment: You cannot solve it without the assumption of a harmonic progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that H.P. means harmonic progression, we have (for $k \neq 0$):
$$a=\frac{1}{x}, \quad b=\frac{1}{x+k}, \quad c=\frac{1}{x+2k}, \quad d=\frac{1}{x+3k}.$$
Then $\frac{a+b}{a-b}-\frac{c+d}{c-d}=\frac{\frac{2x+k}{x(x+k)}}{\frac{k}{x(x+k)}}-\frac{\frac{2x+5k}{(x+2k)(x+3k)}}{\frac{k}{(x+2k)(x+3k)}}=\frac{2x+k}{k}-\frac{2x+5k}{k}=\frac{-4k}{k}=-4.$

It is not possible to solve it without the assumption of some progression, the result is easy in the case of harmonic progression.

Answer (score 0):

a,b,c,d in H.P
1/a,1/b,1/c,1/d  ---A.P
then

(1/b-1/a) = (1/c-1/b) = (1/d-1/c) =k
(a-b)/ab =(c-d)/dc =k--------equ-1 ==(a-b) =kab,(c-d) =kdc

(1/b-1/a) + (1/c-1/b) + (1/d-1/c) =3k
(1/d-1/a) = 3k -----------eq---2

(a+b)/(a-b) -(c+d)/(c-d) = (a+b)/kab-(c+d)/kdc ==1/k{(a+b)/ab-(c+d)/dc}
1/k{1/a+1/b-1/c-1/d}
1/k{1/a-1/d+1/b-1/c}
1/k{-3k-k}=-4 ans

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for mathematical equations.